# error: incompatible types: android.content.Context cannot be converted to com.google.firebase.database.core.Context

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, compiler-errors

public class MyCategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

public MyCategoriesAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_category_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(categoryModelList.get(position).getImage())
            .into(holder.category_iamge);
    holder.category_name.setText(new StringBuilder(categoryModelList.get(position).getName()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryModelList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Unbinder unbinder;
    @BindView(R.id.img_category)
    ImageView category_iamge;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_category)
    TextView category_name;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        unbinder  = ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(categoryModelList.size() == 1)
    {
        return Common.DEAFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
    }
    else
    {
        if(categoryModelList.size() % 2 == 0)
            return Common.DEAFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
        else
            return (position > 1 && position == categoryModelList.size() - 1) ? Common.FULL_WIDTH_COLUMN:Common.DEAFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
    }
}
```

}

here is the full code the contetx is to get datatabase from firebase

i also have this error
error: no suitable method found for with(com.google.firebase.database.core.Context)
method Glide.with(android.content.Context) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to android.content.Context)
method Glide.with(Activity) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to Activity)
method Glide.with(FragmentActivity) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to FragmentActivity)
method Glide.with(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)
method Glide.with(android.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment)
method Glide.with(View) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; com.google.firebase.database.core.Context cannot be converted to View)

Comment: where is context comming from if it's not from the parent ViewGroup. Please add the full code

Comment: i add full code pls check

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide ViewGroup Context :

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_category_item, parent, false)
```

Comment: now its says error: cannot find symbol variable context

Comment: it required viewgroup context